# Flash Builder Localhost works 100% Remote Host just shows title of Object for every entry

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5, flex4.6

I have finally gotten my Flash Builder to look at my remote services but now I have a problem that my Remote information, which should be the same except for alot more entries, just displays each object with the title [object Object] I have had a look around and I see if I test the service out locally, it is working as it calls all the information under Response Name 'object and Response Value 'Object'

On my localhost configuration this shows the name which is inside my Object items. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[object Object] is the result of the toString() method of Object.  If you get this it probably means your custom object type is being returned as a generic object from the remote AMF service.  A lot of things could be the cause of this.  Here are a few to check:

1) Make sure that your custom object type is compiled into the app.  IF the object is never used explicitly the Flex compiler will not put it in the final SWF.  You can do this by creating a fake variable:

```
private var myUnusedObject : MyCustomObjectType;
```

Or, I believe, there is a compiler flag to force unused classes to be compiled into the SWF.

2) You may have to add a formal mapping on your server.  This depends primarily on what server side tech you're using.  In AS3 you add a RemoteAlias metadata to the class.  In ColdFusion you use the alias tag on the cfcomponent tag.  I believe in WerbORB.NET I had to add the mapping in an XML Config file [but it's been years since I've done that].   I assume alternate technologies use similar approaches.

3) Check case sensitivity on the path names for your server code and make sure that the aliases (mentioned in 2) match.

4) In ColdFusion AMF you have to make sure that your public properties and types match up.  They must be in the same order in your AS3 class as they are in your remote CFC.  The property types must match.  String to String; Boolean to Boolean, etc...   I assume other AMF implementations have similar restrictions.

Comment: You were right. It was being returned as a generic object. When I went into the AS files and changed it manually, it seemed to pull through okay.